# Image is not showing in react-leaflet popup (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, react-leaflet

I'm struggling to display the image inside the popup. I use multer with GridFsStorage to store data and images in MongoDB, so they are in a bucket. Then I use gridfs-stream to get the pictures from the bucket.

The image appears in the server browser when I test, but it appears as a white box inside the popup in the client...

**Server**

```
imageRouter.route('/image/:filename')
    .get((req, res) => {
        gfs.files.findOne({filename: req.params.filename}, (err, file) => {
            // Check if file
            if(!file || file.length === 0){
                return res.status(404).json({
                    err: 'No file exists'
                });
            }
            
            // Check if image
            if (file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' || file.contentType === 'image/png' || file.contentType === 'image/heic') {
                // Read output to browser
                const readstream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
                var bufs = [];

                readstream.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    bufs.push(chunk);
                }).on('end', function(){ // done
                    var fbuf = Buffer.concat(bufs);
                    var base64 = (fbuf.toString('base64'));

                    res.send('"data:'+ file.contentType + ';base64,' + base64 + '"');
                    // Shows the image in server browser
                    //res.send('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64 + '">') 
                })
            } else {
                res.status(404).json({
                err: 'Not an image'
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

**Client (App.js)**

```
{
          this.state.images.length > 0 && this.state.images.map(image => (
            <Marker
              key={image._id}
              position={[image.latitude, image.longitude]}
              icon={gpsDirectionMarker}
              rotationAngle={image.GPSImgDirection}>
              <Popup>
                <b>Prosjekt: </b>{image.prosjekt} {image.prosjektOmrade}<p/>
                <b>Parsell: </b>{image.parsell}<p/>
                <b>Kategori: </b>{image.kategori}<p/>
                <b>Høydemeter: </b>{image.GPSAltitude}<p/>
                <b>Dato tatt: </b>{image.captureDate}<p/>
                <img src={`${getPictures(image.imageName)}`} alt={image.imageName} className="popupImage"/>
              </Popup>
            </Marker>
          ))}
```

**Client (API.js)**

```
  export async function getPictures(filename) {
  const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/image/${filename}`);
  return response.json();
}
```

I really hope someone can help me!
Thank you:)

Comment: How does your ${getPictures(image.imageName)} return output look like? I t should be a url coming from your node api in the format of http://localhost:8000/api/myimage.png for instance

Comment: When I check the network tab I can see that the get request is going through without an error, and when I double click I can see the image in the opened url. I tried now to change so that the server is returning the whole <img *with the data* >, but then the popup is showing **[object Promise]** @kboul

Comment: If I copy the response inside the <img src="paste">, then the picture is showing... I don't understand why it is not working then(?) @kboul

Comment: This is where the problem comes from. `src` value should be equal to the exact url when you open it in a tab. And this value is generated by `getPictures` function.

Comment: When I try to `console.log(response.json())` I get **Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0** and then shown an error in the result from the server... @kboul

Comment: I think your promise is not resolved. You should await the result of getPictures and store it in a variable and then use it.